# unexpected 401 on PATCH request of discord api

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm trying to programmatically add a role to a user to indicate their account as 'linked' or 'verified' in relation to my web app. To do so, I take the following steps:

1. in the frontend, send the user to the authorization url to authorize discord
2. when authorized, discord returns to my `redirectURI`, which calls my `/discord/callback` route
3. in this route, I get an `access_token` for the user from `/oauth2/token`
4. with the `access_token`, I get the `discord_user` object from `/users/@me/guilds/${GUILD_ID}/member`

So far, all of those requests are successful, and I get the data I expect. However, when I try to `PATCH` the user, and add a new role, for some reason I get a `401 unauthorized` error, and I'm not entirely sure why. The endpoint I'm using is: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#modify-guild-member

Here's my code for clarity:

```js
const GUILD_ID = '<removed>';
const redirectURI = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/discord/callback';
const encodedRedirectURI = encodeURIComponent(redirectURI);
const url = `https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT}&scope=identify%20guilds.members.read%20guilds.join&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&prompt=consent`

router.get('/discord/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;

  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    params.append('client_id', process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT);
    params.append('client_secret', process.env.DISCORD_SECRET);
    params.append('code', code);
    params.append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:8000/auth/discord/callback');

    let access_token;
    try {
      const tokenRequest = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/oauth2/token`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: params,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      }).then(r => r.json());
  
      access_token = tokenRequest.access_token;
    } catch {
      throw new Error('Failed to get access token.');
    }


    let discord_user;
    try {
      discord_user = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds/${GUILD_ID}/member`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
      }).then(r => r.json());
  
    } catch {
      throw new Error('Failed to get user from guild');
    }
    
    const discord_user_id = discord_user.user.id;

    try {
      await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/${GUILD_ID}/members/${discord_user_id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          roles: [
            'foo',
            ...discord_user.roles
          ],
        }),
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
      }).then(r => r.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data); // 401 unauthorized
        });
    } catch {
      throw new Error('Failed to add role to user');
    }

    return res.redirect('/settings?state=success');
  } catch {
    return res.redirect('/settings?state=failure');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

- The role needs to be the ID of the role, not the name of the role, e.g.: `'957197947676803072'` instead of `'foo'`
- The role setting needs to be done by a bot:

```js
await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/${GUILD_ID}/members/${discord_user_id}`, {
  method: 'PATCH',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    roles: ['957197947676803072', ...discord_user.roles]
  }),
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bot ${process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN}`
  }
}).then(r => r.json())
```

- I also needed to give that bot account admin permissions and manage roles permissions. You can do this either in the invite link or in your discord's server settings.